# Docker OpenProject DB to MySQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, docker

I try to set up an docker container depending on the openproject/community container from docker hub. I have already one openproject running on my machine, and I want to migrate my content from there to the docker container.

The docker container is running without any problems, but I have figured out, that PostgreSQL is used within the container and on my machine I use MySQL instead.

Is there a good way to migrate my MySQL in my container? 
Or better: How can I use MySQL instead of PostgreSQL inside the container?
The last possibility would make it easy to import an MySQL dump.

Thanks and best regards, 
SKiD.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with OpenProject.

When you say that you use MySQL, are you using MySQL w/ OpenProject? Or is MySQL just your preference?

It's considered best practice to run the fewest number of processes in a container. In the case of OpenProject, I assume there is at least some Web/http daemon and the database. In this case, the better practice would be one container for the Web serving components (linked to) another container with the database.

In this scenario, it's easier (not trivial) to not only use your preferred database but to also scale the web-serving separately from the database. if the web-server or app upgrades, the upgrade is easier too.

Anyhoo... I recommend you bug the OpenProject folks and ask them to split the container into >=2 and that they consider enabling Postgres or MySQL as their backend.

You'll be challenged to replace Postgres in their container image.

You *may* be able to export your MySQL database into their Postgres database.

HTH.

Comment: The MySQL database is my preference. The reason is, that I set openproject up with MySQL, but in the community edition of the docker container PostgreSQL is used. The "only" problem is, how to move my MySQL dump in the PostgreSQL database. Normally I would distinguish between a database and web service container, but my knowledge about docker containers and docker compose is not that good and for sure not that helpful for such a complex problem. I will contact the OpenProject team as well, maybe they can help and maybe they follow the advice to split the container up in two. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved similar thing with following docker compose file

```
version: '3'

services:
  openproject:
    image: openproject/community:7.4.3
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=mysql2://root:root@openprojectdb:3306/openproject
      - EMAIL_DELIVERY_METHOD=smtp
      - SMTP_ADDRESS=smtp.sendgrid.net
      - SMTP_PORT=587 
      - SMTP_AUTHENTICATION=login
      - SMTP_ENABLE_STARTTLS_AUTO=true
      - SMTP_USER_NAME=#################
      - SMTP_PASSWORD==#################
      - SECRET_KEY_BASE==#################
    volumes:
      - /var/db/openproject/static:/var/db/openproject 
    ports:
      - 8080:80

  openprojectdb:
    image: mysql:5.6
    volumes:
      - /var/db/openproject/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
```

Few things to keep in mind -

1. Open project version should be exact
2. First dry run compose file, so that containers shoots up, source your mysqldump file and redeploy again.

Also, for single container without using stack/compose, refer official documentation at https://www.openproject.org/docker/ which mentions

> docker run -d ... -e DATABASE_URL=mysql2://user:pass@host:port/dbname
>   openproject/community:8